# How to add verification on email address change?

Tags: email, validation, email-verification, verification

I have custom form for changing email address and it's working perfectly.

However, i realized that i have to add some precautions to prevent my users from using invalid or email address they do not own.

So i was wondering, How do you make or add a verification method which requires users to verify their new email address for it to take effect. **(similar to how the admin email - image below for reference)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add one more field that named status of type Boolean in wp_users table that is 0 or 1 when anyone put mail then you have to check that field if field is 0 then don't update the field and if field is 1 then update the mail.
For updating field 0 to 1 when user click on link that you send in mail.